git difftool not opening remote file
When I do git difftool FILENAME, it opens meld as expected. But the file on left hand side of meld window is not opening i.e. the version which is being compared with the one in local repo (local repo opens on right hand side).
What could be going wrong?
I tried running the git difftool command and got the described output.
